# Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32) low strength signal

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, acer, atheros

I'm very new at linux world so I'm sorry if I do not provide all the required information at once, I recently acquired an Acer switch Alpha 12 2 in 1 tablet/pc which works outstandingly good with Ubuntu 16.04 Gnome in dual boot with Windows 10 (several tweaks required but overall great).

Currently after the Ubuntu installation the Wireless adapter was recognized without problems and I was able to connect to internet (so far so good) but then I had to move a little bit far of my wireless router and find out that the wireless signal was a lot weaker than in windows 10 also unstable. I had tried the following fixes to make the signal strength and stability like windows but non of then had succeeded so far.

I had tried the following fixes:
Install backports 4.4.2-1
make without issues
make install with the following issue:

```
INSTALL /home/northrom/Downloads/backports-4.4.2-1/compat/compat.ko
At main.c:222:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
INSTALL /home/northrom/Downloads/backports-4.4.2-1/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
At main.c:222:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
INSTALL /home/northrom/Downloads/backports-4.4.2-1/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_core.ko
At main.c:222:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
INSTALL /home/northrom/Downloads/backports-4.4.2-1/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_pci.ko
At main.c:222:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
```

Also tried replacing the firmware using the following guidelines:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1520343?comments=all
Used the steps described in the comment #22 without success

Besides those 2 fixes I tried to use ndiswrapper also without success.

Some info I have been seeing as required in the forums for help as following:

lspci -v output

```
Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 280
Memory at b1400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=8/8 Maskable+ 64bit-
Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [148] Virtual Channel
Capabilities: [168] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
Capabilities: [178] Latency Tolerance Reporting
Capabilities: [180] L1 PM Substates
Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
Kernel modules: ndiswrapper
```

lsmod | grep ath10

```
ath10k_pci             45056  0
ath10k_core           311296  1 ath10k_pci
ath                    32768  1 ath10k_core
mac80211              737280  1 ath10k_core
cfg80211              565248  3 ath,mac80211,ath10k_core
```

Iwconfig

```
wlp1s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"XXX-XXX"  
Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: F4:F2:6D:79:3F:95   
Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
Power Management:on
Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-37 dBm  
Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:140   Missed beacon:0
```

uname -r

```
4.4.0-47-generic
```

dmesg | grep ath

```
[    2.359552] audit: type=1400 audit(1478977538.920:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" pid=618 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    2.359569] audit: type=1400 audit(1478977538.920:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/telepathy-*" pid=618 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  146.086338] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[  146.328737] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:01:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[  146.329161] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2
[  146.329172] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
[  146.393873] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin failed with error -2
[  148.512002] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 (0x05030000, 0x00340aff sub 11ad:0807) fw WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 fwapi 4 bdapi 1 htt-ver 3.26 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features wowlan,ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad
[  148.512006] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[  148.578668] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x6c
[  148.578671] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[  148.578673] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[  148.578674] ath: Regpair used: 0x6c
[  148.587387] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
[ 1273.526810] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[ 1273.763382] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:01:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[ 1273.763419] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2
[ 1273.763428] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
[ 1273.826169] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin failed with error -2
[ 1275.944371] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 (0x05030000, 0x00340aff sub 11ad:0807) fw WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 fwapi 4 bdapi 1 htt-ver 3.26 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features wowlan,ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad
[ 1275.944375] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[ 1276.012253] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x6c
[ 1276.012260] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[ 1276.012265] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[ 1276.012268] ath: Regpair used: 0x6c
[ 1276.020002] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
```

So far the wireless adapter has been working since I did install Ubuntu 16.04 but with really weak signal strength and stability.

also as the signal strength drops the data transference ratio does it too from 12MB/s to 1MB/s or less, in windows it works like at 25MB/s that's another issue I have been seeing in local area network.

I'd really appreciate if any help can be provided.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The power management being enabled may be causing part of the problem and you should be able to disable it with

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Reboot

Comment: Did change the value of wifi.powersave to 2 same result wireless signal is very weak also the local download speed is very low.

Second option I did tried was to completely disable power management option, still the same result.

Comment: I used instructions here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269661/how-to-turn-off-wireless-power-management-permanently but that didn't seem to make any difference, either. A year+ on I'm still stuck with incredibly weak signal strength on my otherwise top-notch laptop. Any other ideas out there?